# Windows PE data section mapped to exact address in 32-bit process space

Tags: c++, windows, linker, 32-bit, portable-executable

I am trying to confirm whether data from the executable would always get mapped to the same address in process space after reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx. I.e. image base and base of data are defined in the PE of my executable. So I know where the data segment will start in process space when I add image base to base of data. The question is: is this guaranteed or can OS decide to relocate this to a different address in memory? 
 I tried this on a few Windows XP 32-bit machines and the assumption is correct - the address stays the same and internal pointers stored in the exe don't need any modifications, but on Windows 7 64-bit (running the same 32-bit executable) all the data was shifted and pointers patched. This one is not so important tough as my main question is about the consistency of addresses on a 32-bit Windows OS.
 Thanks!

Comment: Start with Marc Russinovich's talk on this exact subject: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405

Comment: @Mgetz, thx. I tried loading in three browsers (including IE) and it never gets to the actual video. Is this video about mapping of the sections to the virtual addresses as well? Any other ideas links you could share? Thx!

Comment: The preferred address is just a preference. The preference may not be honored if for example the address is not available, or if ASLR is enabled. Windows 7 enables ASLR by default, XP does not.

Comment: @RaymondChen that looks like a great answer, or a good blog... although I thought your blog had already covered ALSR at some point (a cursory search couldn't find it).

Comment: @RaymondChen, oh wow, Raymond Chen here! That's great! I understand that address might not be available but the EXE is always loaded first before any DLLs, so what are the conditions for the address to be unavailable for the executable? Also I'm mainly interested in XP SP3 where ASLR is not available. Thanks!